# How to make CRUD m:m relationship c#

Tags: c#, model

How to make CRUD relationship m:m in my model?

Example:

#### My tables

- People (PeopleId, Name)
- Thing (ThingId, Name)
- PeopleHasThing (PeopleId, ThingId)

#### My Model

PeopleModel.cs:

```cs
    public int PeopleId { get; set; }
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            if(value == _name) return;
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    public List<ThingModel> HasThing
    {
        get { return _hasThing; }

        set
        {
            if(value == _hasThing) return;
            _hasThing= value;
            OnPropertyChanged("HasThing");
        }
    }

    public static int Insert(PeopleModel m)
    {
        using (_context = new myDataContext())
        {
            var d = new People
            {
                Name = m.Name
                Thing = // I don't know how to end this line
            };

            _context.People.InsertOnSubmit(d);
            _context.SubmitChanges();

            return d.PeopleId;
        }
    } 

    // I don't know how to update or retrieve this from the database
    public static void Update(PeopleModel m);
    public static void ListAll();

    // With this I dont have problem! :P
    public static void Delete(int peopleId);
```

PeopleHasThingModel.cs

```cs
    public int PeopleId { get; set; }
    public int ThingId  { get; set; }
```

ThingModel.cs

```cs
    public int ThingId { get; set; }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            if(value == _name) return;
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    public bool IsMarked
    {
        get { return _isMarked; }

        set
        {
            if(value == _isMarked) return;
            _isMarked= value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsMarked");                
        }

    }
```

Thing is a list in my form are a checkbox list populate from thing table.

#### Example

I have 3 records in the `things` table:

```cs
1, "house"
2, "dog"
3, "car"
```

I need to save a new `people` and her `thing`s:

People:

```cs
   1, "ruben"
```

PeopleHasThing:

```cs
   1, 1 -- ruben has house
   1, 3 -- ruben has car
```

### Early approach

PeopleModel.cs

```cs
    public static int Insert(PeopleModel m)
    {
        using (_context = new myDataContext())
        {
            var people = new People
            {
                Name = m.Name
            };

            // Create the PeopleHasThing record
            m.HasThing.ForEach((e) =>
            {
                people.PeopleHasThing.Add(new PeopleHasThing
                {
                    ThingId = e.ThingId,
                    People = people
                });
            });


            _context.People.InsertOnSubmit(people);
            _context.SubmitChanges();

            return people.PeopleId;
        }
    }

    // The following method works!
    // I've tried but I have my doubts about deleting records
    public static void Update(PeopleModel p)
    {
        using (_context = new myDataContext())
        {
            var result = (from r in _context.People
                         where r.PeopleId == p.PeopleId
                         select r).SingleOrDefault();

            if (null == result) return;

            result.Name = p.Name;

            //Delete all PeopleHasThings with result.PeopleId ...

            EntitySet<PeopleHasThing> set = new EntitySet<PeopleHasThing>();
            m.HasThing.ForEach(e =>
            {
                if (e.IsMarked)
                {
                    set.Add(new PeopleHasThing
                    {
                        ThingId = e.ThingId,
                        People = result
                    });
                }
            });

            result.PeopleHasThing = set;

            _context.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is m:m? And what exactly is the question?

Comment: @mperrenoud03: Obviously it's "many to many" given the context.

Comment: @SergioTapia My apologies - for whatever reason it was a bit fuzzy to me.

Answer (score 0):

Your 3 models would look like this:

```
class PeopleModel {
  public int PeopleID { get; set; }
  public string Name  { get; set; }
  /* .. additional fields or values .. */
}

class ThingsModel {
  public int ThingsID { get; set; }
  public string Name  { get; set; }
  /* .. additional fields or values .. */
}

class PeopleHasThing {
  public int PersonID { get; set; }
  public int ThingsID { get; set; }
}
```

You can approach this with the 3 table model by housing only *people* related fields in the **People** table & only *thing* related fields in the **Things** table.

Then, you would house all of your relationships in the PeopleHasThing table with as many rows as needed.

As you create/edit People & Things, you need to know the ID # to build your relationships

```
PeopleModel myPerson = new PeopleModel();
myPerson.PeopleID // ID of Person
ThingsModel myThing = new ThingsModel();
myThings.ThingsID // ID of Thing

PeopleHasThings relationship = new PeopleHasThings();
relationship.PeopleID = myPerson.PeopleID;
relationship.ThingsID = myThings.ThingsID;
```

**Example**

People:

```
1, "ruben"
2, "joe"
```

Things:

```
1, "house"
2, "dog"
3, "car"
```

PeopleHasThing:

```
1, 1 -- ruben has house
1, 3 -- ruben has car
2, 1 -- joe has house
```

Comment: I know what is the idea, so i don't how to implement it

Comment: you solution have a problem i dont know the PeopleId becouse People is new